# wget command line - define format and encoding

Tags: rest, wget

trying to download all categories from an ecommerce website using rest and wget (curl either) I cannot make a readable file. the following line is the one that Im executing:

```
...>wget https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/categories/all --no-check-certificate
```

I receive information like this->

```
½Û’Û8².ü*_[6q Hö]>t{\=¶ÇëðÇŽˆ¢ªè–ÄÜmïXûÖôeÇŽ¹˜˜»û®^ìHU €()‰dåŠ1]ì®,$&
```

I expected something like:

```
, {
    "id": "MLA1743",
    "name": "Autos, Motos y Otros"
}, {
    "id": "MLA1384",
    "name": "Bebés"
}, {
    "id": "MLA1039",
    "name": "Cámaras y Accesorios"
}, {
    "id": "MLA1051",
    "name": "Celulares y Teléfonos"
}, {
    "id": "MLA1798",
    "name": "Coleccionables y Hobbies"
}
```

sorry if its a newbie question but i cannot find a proper tutorial. brgds

Answer (score 2):

The content is gzip-encoded.  You can figure this out by looking at the `Content-Encoding` header the servers sends with the response.  You can access the data like this:

```
wget -o- https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/categories/all | zcat
```

Or just save it to a file first:

```
wget -o all.gz https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLB/categories/all
gunzip all.gz
```

Comment: im using version 1.11 for windows.. I believe that version dont have -o option. I receive an error. Im trying to make an exe version of new wget 1.19 to see if its works.

Comment: in windows 1.13 version -o option works but encoding have same problems.